# Recover PostgreSQL password with admin access to host

Tags: postgresql

Good day.

I have a **PostgreSQL** server.

Once i had admin login and password, then i created a new login for web application (with low permissions like select form some tables etc). And i just lost my admin login and password.

I have access (administator) to host where the server is running. Server is windows 2008 server.
Is there any way to recover admin permissions? May be i somehow could create another superuser?

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to fix. Edit `pg_hba.conf` to add a line like this:

```
host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 trust
```

(You may need to restart Postgres server after editing it).

Then, use this:

```
psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

You should be able to get admin access without password now (that's why you added `trust` rule to `pg_hba.conf`).

Once this command works, change your password:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD 'newpassword';
```

After doing this, edit `pg_hba.conf` to remove line you added.

Comment: A `pg_ctl reload` is sufficient, but it's sufficiently hard to do that on Windows that restarting the service via the Services control panel (`services.msc`) is going to be easier.